# Find img with querySelector and show it in new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js function, that by clicking on button while overlay effect appear should select an image in current section and than show this image in new div.
I use query selector, but I guess I use it the wrong way, cause the function isn't work. Where did I mistake? or maybe it should go with another method?

```
<div class="lots">
<div class="f-lot" >
            <div class="overlay" >
            <input type="button"  value="choice"   name="myBtn"  
            onclick="prChoice()"/>
            </div>
            <label for="choice" >           
                <img src="lot1.jpg>             
            </label>                    
            </div>

        <div class="f-lot">
        <div class="overlay">
            <input type="radio"  value="choice1"  name="myBtn" onclick="prChoice()"/>
            </div>
            <label for="choice1">               
                <img src="lot2.jpg">
            </label>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="newsection"></div>

<script>    
 function prChoice(elem){
  var div = document.getElementById('newsection');
  var val=elem.document.querySelector('.f-lot > img');
 div.innerHTML +=' <img src="'+val+'">'
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Your image is not a direct child of `f-lot` so remove the `>`

Comment: And one more thing is, you can even use `.detach()` and `.appendTo()` jQuery functions for these as you have tagged your question with jQuery.

Comment: Why even bother with `querySelector()` and `getElementById()` when you can use jQuery for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
function prChoice(elem) {
  var div = document.getElementById('newsection');
  var val = elem.closest(".f-lot").querySelector('img');
  div.innerHTML += ' <img src="' + val.src + '">'
}
```

Please note that your first `<img src="lot1.jpg>` is missing the closing `"`

Also you need to add `this` to `onclick="prChoice()"` because if not, then your function will not know what `elem` is

**Demo**

```js
function prChoice(elem) {
  var div = document.getElementById('newsection');
  var val = elem.closest(".f-lot").querySelector('img');
  div.innerHTML += ' <img src="' + val.src + '">'
}
```

```html
<div class="lots">
  <div class="f-lot">
    <div class="overlay">
      <input type="button" value="choice" name="myBtn" onclick="prChoice(this)" />
    </div>
    <img src="lot1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="f-lot">
    <div class="overlay">
      <input type="button" value="choice" name="myBtn" onclick="prChoice(this)" />
    </div>
    <img src="lot2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="newsection"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use from **querySelector** :

```
var src= document.querySelector("#id-for-image img").src;
```

Note that the selector must be compatible with the CSS norm. That means that your id must not start with a digit.

If you really can't fix your id (which is bad because it will lead to other problems), then you can use this kind of selector :

```
var src= document.querySelector('[id="0a03"] img').src;
```

Comment: What ID are you talking about, In the OP's code there is only 1 ID and that is not the main problem

Answer (score 0):

you better use the appendChild, if you just copy the image to the new section:

```
function prChoice(elem){
   var div = document.getElementById('newsection');
   var img = elem.document.querySelector('.f-lot img')// here you get the element not the src, so can not assign the element to the img src;
   div.appendChild(img.cloneNode());
}
```